# How can I implement a data structure which calculates the number of nested intervals in sub-linear time?

Tags: data-structures, intervals

Is there a data structure which can maintain a list of intervals and the following operations?

```
insert(l, r): Inserts an interval [l, r] into the list
query(l, r): Return the number of intervals in the list which are completely nested in [l, r]
```

I need the data structure to handle inserting and querying without brute force (which would take linear time).

I saw this algorithm for counting the number of nested intervals for each interval here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946497/sub-on2-algorithm-for-counting-nested-intervals
but it appears to only calculate the answer for a static array of intervals.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for an [interval tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)?

Comment: An interval tree can only answer 'how many intervals overlap with a given interval', but I'm looking for the number of intervals which are entirely contained within an interval.

Comment: You could modify the query algorithm by filtering all the overlapping intervals which are completely contained in the query-interval, but perhaps there's a better option.

Comment: Treat your intervals as 2D points. Essentially, you need to find the number of points $(x,y)$ such that $x \ge l$ and $y \le r$. This can be solved using e.g. [2D segment tree](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html#toc-tgt-11) or [QuadTrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Dmitry's comment, you can maintain a balanced tree with the left endpoints of the intervals as the keys, and at each node store a balanced tree with the right endpoints as keys, and at each node of each of those trees store a count of intervals.

This requires $O(n\log n)$ space. Lookups are $O(\log^2 n)$. Insertions are tricky because when rebalancing the outer tree you have to rebuild the inner trees, but I think it can be made amortized polylog(n) if you rebalance sufficiently rarely, using a [scapegoat tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapegoat_tree) for example.

If you know that the endpoints will belong to a set of size $k$, and you don't mind factors of $\log k$ in the insertion and lookup times, then you could use a radix tree for the outer tree and avoid the rebalancing logic.